# Detecting parasites on unsecure wireless

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, users

Is it possible to find out who is connected to an unsecured wireless network?
If so, how?

OS: Windows Vista, Wireless N

Comment: Do you have physical access to the router ?

Comment: @Studer - "Do you have physical access to the router?" Like open the router and look for lice with a magnifying glass? Or do you mean access to the HTML Web interface with user name and password (which isn't really 'physical')?

Comment: @Molly : As this is an open network, having a physical access to the router (being able to plug an ethernet cable in it) is not mandatory, knowing the admin password is enough. I forget this when I posted my first comment.

Comment: Yes, i have physical access to the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to check if other people are using it so that you can block them, which means you'd have some sort of access to the router. In that case, gshankar's answer should suffice. If that's not the case, and you're just curious to see who's using it, you can grab [WireShark](http://wireshark.org/) and so some [WLAN Capturing](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) in promiscuous mode. This should be exceptionally easy with an unsecured connection.

If you actually do have access to the router, I'd recommend securing it as soon as possible. ISPs may put the blame on you if others are downloading illegal content on your connection. You are liable for securing your network.

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin access to the router (the web interface) you can just look at what IPs are assigned